# How do I call a JavaScript function with a variable name that is only known at runtime?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables, loops

For this problem I have a snippet of PHP code that looks in a directory and returns a list of files. I then walk through the array and store each file name as a JavaScript variable using echo

Consider the the following example witch does not include the PHP used to generate the image names:

```
//result of PHP
image1="cow.jpg"  
image2="pig.jpg"
image3="dog.jpg"

imgIndex=0 //global variable that will be incremented

function setBG(image) {
    someElement.style.backgroundImage= "url(/images/" + image + ")"
};

function nextBG(){
    imgIndex++
    currentIMG="image"+imgIndex;
    setBG(currentIMG);
};
```

When called function `nextBG()` will not work. But this will:

```
function nextBG(){
    setBG(image1);
};
```

I believe the reason it is not working is because the second example is calling the function using the value of the defined variable (cow.jpg).  But the first example is calling the function using the string `"image1"`, witch is obviously not a path name for an image.

Is there a way for me to call the function using the variable `image1`, then `image2` and then `image3` and so on without it being interpreted as just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your variables members of an object. Then you can use [] to access the objects members using a string:

```
var images = {
  image1 : "cow.jpg",  
  image2 : "pig.jpg",
  image3 : "dog.jpg"
};

function nextBG(){
    imgIndex++
    currentIMG="image"+imgIndex;
    setBG(images[currentIMG]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to store all of your images in an array:

```
var bgImages = [
    // All can be got with a call to encode your PHP array as JSON.
    "cow.jpg",
    "horse.jpg",
    "dog.jpg",
    "pig.jpg"
    ],
    imageIndex = 0,
    maxLength = bgImages.length - 1;

function setBG(image) {
    someElement.style.backgroundImage= "url(/images/" + image + ")"
};

function nextBG(){
    var currentIMG = bgImages[imageIndex];
    setBG(currentIMG);
    imageIndex = imageIndex > maxLength ? 0 : imageIndex + 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because currentIMG is a string, not a variable. Here's what you want to do. You have your array $images, which is just image names. In your HTML, you do this

```
var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
```

And then you can use JavaScript as such

```
for(var i=0; var i < images; i++)
{
    setBG(images[i]);
}
```